AIX 5.3 system returning ? for special characters in filenames
I am trying to get filenames containing special characters on an AIX 5.3 system using a Java program but its replacing the special characters with a question mark. This is in client environment. But when I use the same program in our dev environment, I cant reproduce the issue.
I tried both vfs2 and jsch libraries but same issue on both of them. This is the sample code I have tried-
package com.example.ftp;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Elmer1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "aix";
        String username = "user";
        int port = 22;
        String password = "pass";  // Replace with your password
        String remoteDirectory = "/disk1/users/usr1";  // Replace with the remote folder path

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;

        try {
            // Create the session object
            session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);  // Set password

            // Create properties for key exchange, ciphers, and host key algorithms
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();

            session.setConfig(config);

            // Disable strict host key checking for testing purposes (optional)
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

            // Connect to the session
            session.connect();

            // Open an SFTP channel
            ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
            channelSftp.connect();

            // List files and directories in the remote directory
            Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = channelSftp.ls(remoteDirectory);

            System.out.println("Contents of " + remoteDirectory + ":");
            for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : list) {
                if (entry.getAttrs().isDir()) {
                    // It's a directory
                    System.out.println("[DIR]  " + entry.getFilename());
                } else {
                    // It's a file
                    System.out.println("[FILE] " + entry.getFilename());
                }
            }

            // Disconnect when done
            channelSftp.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();

        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Output in dev environment-
Contents of /disk1/users/usr1:
[DIR]  .
[DIR]  ..
[FILE] 99-4±±±±0A02-|PART±ASSEMBLY,±SAMPLE±IV-X.model

Not sure what could be causing this issue in the customer environment. Appreciate any pointers/ inputs to try to fix this problem.

What locale is installed in AIX? Output in dev environment- - that's presumably correct then?

This is the output of AIX locale in the client environment and it matches with dev environment-
$ locale
LANG=EN_US
LC_COLLATE="EN_US"
LC_CTYPE="EN_US"
LC_MONETARY="EN_US"
LC_NUMERIC="EN_US"
LC_TIME="EN_US"
LC_MESSAGES="EN_US"
LC_ALL=
$
The output in dev environment is the expected one.

locale charmap might be of interest

channelSftp.connect();channelSftp.setFilenameEncoding("ISO8859-1")); might fit

Immediately elete any files with non-ASCII characters in their names (same for control-characters 0x00-0x1f, 0x7f). They have been created with malicious intent.

The question's title mentions special characters being replaced by question marks, but I don't see any question marks in the sample output. Could you provide an example? Also: are both client environments logging in to the same system as the same user and listing the same directory?

@JeffSchaller- Sorry about the confusion. The dev output is expected and its not reproducible in dev environment. The intent to add the dev output was to mention the special characters in the filename.

One thing that might be useful is to do ls '99-4±±±±0A02-|PART±ASSEMBLY,±SAMPLE±IV-X.model' | hexdump or maybe  ls '99-4±±±±0A02-|PART±ASSEMBLY,±SAMPLE±IV-X.model' | xxd


Install the same localization-packages on the production host that are installed on the development host, e.g.
 bos.loc.com.utf     Common Locale Support - UTF-8
 bos.loc.iso.en_US   Base System Locale ISO Code Set - U.S. English
 bos.loc.utf.EN_US   Base System Locale UTF Code Set - U. S. English


Make sure environment variable LC_CTYPE is set the same way on the production host as it is on develepment host. (Java properties file.encoding and sun.jnu.encoding are set based on LC_CTYPE)

Try your best not to have non-ASCII characters in your file-names. Those are nothing but trouble.


